# Why the event trigger immediately when I just dispatch it?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, dom-events

I would like do something when i click element `#b` then dispatch an other event listener before `handleB()` finished

When I was clicked `#b` the event `click` on `#a` has dispatch successful and it has also triggered but I don't wanna trigger it

What's going on here??

```js
document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('click', handleB)

function handleB() {
  alert('Handle B!');
  document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('click', handleA)
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  AAA
  <div id="b">BBB</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Event bubbling up to the `a` element?

Comment: You don't have `handleA` function ?

Comment: Stop the event bubbling: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/myobcezw/

Comment: Most events bubble up the DOM tree, so your `a` element also receives the click on `b`. And since you added a click handler to it inside `b`, it gets triggered immediately. Use `event.stopPropagation();` inside `handleB` to stop the click from going up the DOM tree any further.

Comment: It is bubble up rightbut I am so confuse because JS is a async program so When I trigger the #b `click enent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of the event of #b bubbles up to #a and since you have added the click event listener inside handleB. It triggers immediately with the event of #b. You have to stop the event to bubble up. Below is the working example:

```js
document.getElementById('b').addEventListener('click', handleB);

function handleB(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('b clicked');
  document.getElementById('a').addEventListener('click', handleA)
}

function handleA() {
  console.log('a clicked');
}
```

```css
#a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

#b {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b"></div>
</div>
```